# How to make postfix create maildir?

Tags: postfix, maildir

How do you make postfix create maildir folders automatically for all users?

I have these two lines in postfix main.cf, which supposed do create maildir folder after the first mail but it is not working. What am I missing?

```
home_mailbox = Maildir 
mailbox_command =
```

At the moment mail looks to sent, but nowhere to be found.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `home_mailbox = Maildir/` with a slash (`/`) at the end if you want a qmail-style directory? See the documentation for [**home_mailbox**](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#home_mailbox).

Comment: And with the slash: postfix creates non-existent Maildirs itself.

Answer (score 14):

Cristian's comment is correct: you need a trailing slash to make Postfix store incoming mail in Maildir format:

```
home_mailbox = Maildir/
```

If you leave it off, it stores the mail in an [mbox-style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox) file of the same name.

That is to say, this is not a setting where you are providing the *name* of a type of storage, you are providing the name of a file or directory, and Postfix infers mbox vs Maildir based on the trailing slash only. It will use any directory name you put here, not just `Maildir`.